# Why are rank-one matrices with nonzero traces diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$, with non-zero trace and rank $1$, why does it always hold that $A$ is diagonalizable? I think it is because of the fact that this matrix has an eigenvalue $0$ with $n-1$ geometric multiplicity, but I don't really get this fact either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer is that non-zero trace allows us to construct a basis of eigenvectors.

**Proof:** Since $A$ has rank $1$, there exists a vector $v_1$ such that all columns of $A$ are scalar multiples of $v_1$. In other words, there exists a vector $u_1$ such that

$$
A = v_1u_1^H.
$$

Complete $v_1$ to an orthonormal basis $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and $u_1$ to an orthonormal basis $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$.

Now define $\lambda = u_1^Hv_1$ and note that

$$
\lambda = u_1^Hv_1 = {\rm tr}(A) \ne 0
$$

and so $v_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ is a basis. Moreover

$$
Av_1 = \lambda v_1 \\
Au_2 = 0 \\
\dots \\
Au_n = 0
$$

so $v_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ is a basis of eigenvectors of $A$. Conclusion follows from the fact that every matrix with a basis of eigenvectors is diagonalizable.

**Remark:** Note that if trace is zero then $A$ is nilpotent and the only nilpotent matrix which is diagonalizable is the zero matrix.